# Using tab as sed separator

Tags: sed, syntax

I would like to include tab as delimited new row to a file `inp.txt`.

This is the input produced by R:

```
inp <- 'AX-1   1    125
        AX-2   2    456
        AX-3   3    3445'
inp <- read.table(text=inp, header=F)
write.table(inp, "inp.txt", col.names=F, row.names=F, quote=F, sep="\t")
```

That´s what I am trying to do:

```
sed -i '1i The name\tThe pos\tThe pos2\' inp.txt
```

However, those three col names: 1- `The name`, 2- `The pos`, 3- `The pos2` are not separated by tab in the output file. It just contain the `\t` string. Someone can help me here with the syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the tab in a variable:

```
tab=$(echo "\t")
```

or

```
tab=$'\t'
```

Then you can use it in your `sed` script:

```
sed -i "1i The name${tab}The pos${tab}The pos2" inp.txt
```